# How to delete selected checkbox rows in an Oracle APEX Classic Report using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, oracle11g, oracle-apex

Within Oracle APEX v4.2.2, I have a simple classic report that has as a first column, a checkbox `f50` setup attached to the table's ID column, which will allow a user to check all or specific rows and remove these records from the report/table.

An example report might be something like:

```
ID     Col2    Col3    Col4
----------------------------
1      10      20      30
2      5       8       9
3      92      88      12
4      1       2       44
5      95      77      88
```

The requirement I am after is that I want to perform this whole process of checking the IDs and the removal of these records done without having to submit the whole page but would like it done via an AJAX method using `apex.process.server` if possible.

**UPDATE:** Just a bit more background on this requirement based on the report I am attempting to hook this apex.process.server checkbox IDs, i.e.:

ID Report Column above within Report Attributes heading looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox"  label="Select Code" onclick="$f_CheckFirstColumn(this)" />
```

Drilling down into this ID column under HTML Expression is the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" #ID# value="#ID#" name="f50" id="f50_#ROWNUM#"/>
```

**Region Source:**

```
SELECT A.ID,
       A.REQ_NO COL2,
       A.CODE_ID||apex_item.hidden(20, A.CODE_ID)||apex_item.hidden(30, A.ID) COL3,
       GROUP_VALUE COL4
FROM MY_TABLE A
WHERE A.REQ_NO = :REQ_NO
```

I believe inorder to have APEX store the values within the `apex_application.g_f50.count`array of the IDs to be removed, the page needs to be submitted.

Using `apex.process.server`, can the ids, as they are checked, be passed as a JavaScript array to an on demand process that will then use these ids to perform the required delete operation?

How can I achieve the above via an AJAX means (no page refresh at all)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this query for a report

```
select 
 "EMPNO",
 "ENAME",
 apex_item.checkbox2(2, 0) check1,
 apex_item.checkbox2(3, 0) check2,
 apex_item.checkbox2(4, 0) check3
from EMP
```

With `EMPNO` set to "Hidden" - so it'll generate a hidden input item appended to the last column.

To update a certain record you'll need a PK and a value to update the row with. That is why I'm using `EMPNO`. I'll pass that to the on-demand process.

```
function selectorToArray(pSelector){
  function getVal(pNd){
    switch ( pNd.nodeName ) {
      case "INPUT":
        switch ( pNd.type ) {
          case "checkbox":
            return $(pNd).prop("checked");
            break;
          default: 
            return $(pNd).val();
        };
        break;
      default:
        return $(pNd).val()
    };
  };

  var lArray = [];
  $(pSelector).each(function(){
    lArray.push(getVal(this));
  });
  return lArray;  
};
```

The function `selectorToArray` will fetch the values for the given selector to an array and get the value. As you might know, you can pass values to a process with `x01, x02, ...` But there are also arrays: `f01, f02,...`
With the following code you can send values over to the ondemand process:

```
function sendCheckboxes(){
  var lf01 = [], lf02 = [], lf03 = [], lf04 = [];
  lf01 = selectorToArray("input[name=f01]");
  lf02 = selectorToArray("input[name=f02]");
  lf03 = selectorToArray("input[name=f03]");
  lf04 = selectorToArray("input[name=f04]");

  apex.server.process("PROCESS_CHECKBOXES", {f01: lf01, f02: lf02, f03: lf03, f04: lf04});
};
```

You can use those just like you would otherwise: loop over them:

```
DECLARE
  l_pk VARCHAR2(30);
  l_check1 VARCHAR2(30);
  l_check2 VARCHAR2(30);
  l_check3 VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
  -- f01: PK 
  -- f02: checkbox values column1
  FOR i IN 1..apex_application.g_f01.count
  LOOP
    l_pk := apex_application.g_f01(i);
    l_check1 := apex_application.g_f02(i);
    l_check2 := apex_application.g_f03(i);
    l_check3 := apex_application.g_f04(i);
    apex_debug.message('Record with PK '||l_pk||': check1? '||NVL(l_check1, 'NO')||': check2? '||NVL(l_check2, 'NO')||': check3? '||NVL(l_check3, 'NO'));
  END LOOP;
END;
```

---

In your code, there are 3 item arrays: `f20`, `f30` and `f50`. `f30` holds the row PK value, while `f50` is used for the checkbox.
Don't be fooled by the array naming. Apex itself uses the f## arrays for submission, true enough. And your items with name `f50` will indeed be in array `g_f50` on page submit.
You can however also use arrays `f01` to `f20` (don't think it goes up to 50) for ajax calls! They're a great addition to the variables `x01-x20`!
When using the arrays to send a bulk of values to your process, instead of one-by-one, I think it's most useful to not just send an array of PK values, with a position-matched array of values to interact with. This isn't as valuable when you use a report without pagination though, but still. With pagination, the idea is that you don't really know what set of data was just interacted with. Of 100 records, 10 rows were presented. Of those 10 rows, 6 were checked on render, and on submit only 5 are. Which ones are checked and which ones are unchecked. Knowing which 5 are checked doesn't mean you know the unchecked ones.
When you include a PK column however, you'll always have those 10 rows and you're able to identify clearly which records has been checked or unchecked.
For instance, 10 records in your report will (=should!) mean that 10 values are put in an array (eg `l_f01`) with the PK value and 10 more values are put in another array (eg `l_f02`) with eg a checked indicator. So when passing those on to the on-demand process, you'll be able to loop over array `f01` reliably, and fetch the checked or unchecked indicator from array `f02` with your current index variable used for `f01`.

Plainly put, you're building up 2 arrays with this sort of value set:

```
f01 - IDs | f02 - checkeds
----------|---------------
4520      | false
4521      | true
4527      | false
4561      | true
4578      | true
```

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for your solution but unfortunately still experiencing issues with what I have at the moment and trying to fit your feedback into my code. Based on this, I have updated my original post above to include more info on the arrays I am using, i.e. f50 for ID and some other arrays. I attempted to retrofit your code into mine but I think the issue is trying to figure out in your PROCESS_CHECKS on demand process, exactly which IDs have actually been selected. Based on my updates, are you able to see what changes I require from yours inorder to retrieve the IDs that have been checked.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for the updated answer but sorry, still trying to understand this, b/c I am using f30 and f50 non ajax arrays, instead of say, f01 and f02 ajax arrays, is this the reason I am not seeing any checked values going into my ondemand process? Do I need to use f01 and f02 convention for what I am trying to achieve? Thanks.

Comment: Yes Tony, the arrays you can use to send arrays to the db are limited to only 20 arrays, f01 through f20. Meaning, you need to gather data from elements with name f30 from the DOM, store them in an array in javascript, and then provide that array to one of the arrays you can use in the on-demand process. Bear in mind, the array used for normal page submission is irrelevant for on-demand. While the different arrays may be throwing you off a bit, they're simply not related. apex.server.process docs: "(for example you can set the scalar parameters x01 - x10 and the arrays f01 - f20)."

Comment: Hi Tom, I've come back to this thread as I'm finding issues with passing over the checkboxes that have been "checked". I found that your apex_application.g_f01.count did not bring any results over and so were not able to find out the checked values. Are you able to provide an actual example on apex.oracle.com - thanks.

Comment: @tonsils It was likely my use of .val() on a checkbox item. It doesn't take account of whether the box is checked or not. It is necessary to test this first and then get the value. I changed my code above to use ´.prop()´ to determine the state of the checkbox, and just push ´true´ or ´false´ to the process. `$v()` will take in account the state. When checked it will provide the checbox value, otherwise it'll be empty. Doesn't matter what you choose though, you'll always need to perform a binary test.